# Componentart Dialog not run in IE (Unable to get property 'clear' of undefined or null reference )

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I just setup a new website on Azure using the GSP template that they have available. It sets itself up and I am able to open the site in a browser. However, when I attempt to login I am unable. Looking at the browser debug there is an error message: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'clear' of undefined or null reference 
ComponentArtScript.axd, line 1 character 8069. I can't find that file but I can pull it up with a link in the log and this is the code it is having trouble with _27.filters.clear(). Any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently with the modal control. The error is related to some animation properties used by ComponentArt controls.

According to the [ComponentArt support forums](http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/t/64423.aspx),

> I can confirm that this is a new issue, unfortunately, related to
> animation and filters. I'll log this now, but in the interim you can get rid of the error by removing the two transitions and the expanddelay setting.
>
> <sup>[Stephen Hatcher](http://www.componentart.com/community/search/searchresults.aspx?u=8500&o=DateDescending), Developer Support Manager</sup>

I removed all animation properties from my modal control and everything works properly (sans any fancy animation).

I haven't verified this, but you may also try updating to the latest version of ComponentArt UI Framework.